# Virtuoso Sesame HTTP Repository Configuration, Exception

Tags: virtuoso, sesame

I got a problem while configuring the Virtuoso Sesame HTTP Repository following the "Setup RDF4J or Sesame HTTP Repository" part of this web page, [Virtuoso Sesame HTTP Repository Configuration and Usage](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSesame2HttpRepository)

It threw the following Exception after I clicked the "create" button, I did not find the solution.
[image: create a Virtuoso RDF Store]

[image: exception]

The full stack trace in the logs are:

```
Feb 16, 2017 2:46:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
严重: Servlet.service() for servlet workbench threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.getConfigTemplate(CreateServlet.java:159)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.createRepositoryConfig(CreateServlet.java:130)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.commands.CreateServlet.doPost(CreateServlet.java:75)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.TransformationServlet.service(TransformationServlet.java:95)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:137)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.ProxyRepositoryServlet.service(ProxyRepositoryServlet.java:104)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:222)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.handleRequest(WorkbenchServlet.java:151)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchServlet.service(WorkbenchServlet.java:119)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.WorkbenchGateway.service(WorkbenchGateway.java:131)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.base.BaseServlet.service(BaseServlet.java:137)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.openrdf.workbench.proxy.CookieCacheControlFilter.doFilter(CookieCacheControlFilter.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

And I tried "Setup RDF4J or Sesame Console Repository" part to create a virtuoso rdf store, still got an error: 
[image: Unsupported repository type: openrdf:VirtuosoRepository]

What's wrong with my operations and what should I do?
BTW, my sesame was normal, and creating a store of another RDF type is successful except virtuoso. I have installed virtuoso through brew, and it works properly.

Appreciate that.

Answer (score 1):

What is the version of Virtuoso being used?

Note that you need to be using the latest 7.2 release of either [Commercial](http://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/download/) or [Open Source](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/dav/wiki/Main/VOSDownload), with the latest [Providers for RDF4J](https://virtuoso.openlinksw.com/dataspace/doc/dav/wiki/Main/VirtSesame2Provider#Setup).

Also, ensure these Providers are in the correct location, as the error being reported setting up the Console Repo indicates that the `VirtuosoRepository` is an unsupported repository type.